# cakephp 3 is there something like autoFields for joins to select all fields of a join?

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I have a query which selects some computed field. In order to get all other fields of the main model and associated models, I can use `autoFields(true)`. I also need to join some tables on certain conditions.

So far the query looks like this:

```
$functionsBuilder = $this->MainModel->find()->func();
$documents = $this->MainModel->find('all', [
    'conditions' => […],
    'contain' => […],
    'join' => [
        'table' => 'tablename',
        'alias' => 'AliasName',
        'type' => 'LEFT',
        'foreignKey' => false,
        'conditions' => […],
    ],
])
->autoFields(true)
->select([
    'computed_field_name' => $functionsBuilder->group_concat(['OtherModel.name' => 'literal']),
]);
```

The fields of the joined table are not included in the result. Usually when you want to include all fields of an associated table, you do a `select` call with the table class as a parameter, e.g. `->select($this->MainModel->AssociatedModel)`.

The table used in the join might not be any (deeper) association with the main model. Even **if** it also is an association, the alias defined in the join might be a different one.

What I came up with so far is to load the table class for the table referenced in the join, then change its alias, and then use that in a select. Yielding:

```
$this->loadModel('AssociatedModel');
$this->AssociatedModel->alias('AliasName');
$functionsBuilder = $this->MainModel->find()->func();
$documents = $this->MainModel->find('all', [
    'conditions' => […],
    'contain' => […],
    'join' => [
        'table' => 'tablename',
        'alias' => 'AliasName',
        'type' => 'LEFT',
        'foreignKey' => false,
        'conditions' => […],
    ],
])
->autoFields(true)
->select($this->AssociatedModel)
->select([
    'computed_field_name' => $functionsBuilder->group_concat(['OtherModel.name' => 'literal']),
]);
```

The result then contains all fields from the join with the correct *AliasName*.

I was just wondering whether there is a better way to do this. If I have a lot of joins I need to load a lot of table classes and alias them correctly. It is doable, but is there maybe a more elegant solution?